# Making sense of mutual fund returns

Tags: india, interest-rate

Looking at a mutual funds returns, sometimes I see a 5 year return of 20% and 1 year return of 100% (both annualized). Does that imply that the growth was 0 in the year n-5 to n-1, and the growth of 100% in year n-1 is what accounted for the 5 year return of 20%?

Comment: More likely that the growth bounced up and down for the first four years and the fifth year was a bumper.

Answer (score 1):

A 5-year annualized return of 20% means that, if the returns in each year were `a, b , c, d, e`, then `a*b*c*d*e = (1.2)^5 = 2.488...`.  A 1-year return of 100% means `e = 2`.  So all you know is that `a*b*c*d = 2.488/2 = 1.244` --- that is, that the total (non-annualized) return over the first four years combined was about 24%.  You don't know what ups and downs happened in which years.

Four years of 0% returns followed by a year of 100% return would not result in a 20% annualized return over five years, because annualized returns use the geometric mean, not the arithmetic mean (see [here](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/annualized-total-return.asp) for instance).  That pattern of returns would give `(1*1*1*1*2)^(1/5) = 1.148...`, or an annualized 5-year return of about 15%.